# Link to enum member in Javadoc

Tags: java, enums, javadoc

In Javadoc how can I link to a particular enum value instead of the enum class itself?

```
public enum SomeJavaCass {
    SOME_ENUM;
}
```

for the enum above is there a way to do like:

```
/** 
  * {@link SomeJavaClass.SOME_ENUM}
  */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same as any class member:

```
/**
 * {@link SomeJavaClass#SOME_ENUM}
 */
```

Comment: Yeah after I asked the question, I found the solution. Thanks for the time!